# Possible problems in moving linux disks from one hardware to another

Tags: linux, drivers, raid

I currently have a server collocated in a datacenter.
The hardware is a HP dual quad core xeon with 16 Gb DDR2 and 2 1Gb disks in raid1.
I want to order another similar server to have as a replacement, if the first server has a hardware issue I can just move the disks to the replacement and not lose time debugging the hardware problem while the server is down.

The problem in this situation is that I can't find the exact same hardware to buy as a replacement so I will have to buy something similar.
My question is, what problems can I face when moving the disks to the new hardware, can I encounter any driver issues or something similar or it should work without a problem as long as the cpu architecture is the same (intel xeon x64) ?

Thank you.

Comment: Hardware raid? If so the new controller has to be able to import the raid info.

Answer (score 4):

If you're using a standard kernel, it should run on pretty much every hardware, so moving disks from one box to another shouldn't be a problem. That's the theory anyway.

However, it may be a different story if it's using some kind of hardware RAID that may not be compatible with another hardware RAID controller.

Same for brand-new or exotic hardware that just isn't supported by Linux directly, or by whatever stone-age distro you have installed on that box.

Other problems you may face is broken network connectivity due to changed MAC address (if your system or datacenter depends on that) or, if it's Linux with recent udev, due to different naming for the ethernet device.

In the end, this is something you have to test. Too many variables involved for a yes or no answer.

Comment: The raid is software, forgot to mention that and the OS is centos 6 x64 so I don't think I'll have problems with the OS.

Answer (score 1):

As per HP [doc](http://h20566.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/template.BINARYPORTLET/public/kb/docDisplay/resource.process/?spf_p.tpst=kbDocDisplay_ws_BI&spf_p.rid_kbDocDisplay=docDisplayResURL&javax.portlet.begCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken&spf_p.rst_kbDocDisplay=wsrp-resourceState=docId%253Demr_na-c03326739-2%257CdocLocale%253D&javax.portlet.endCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken) (See Moving hard drives and arrays) on SmartArray it seems possible depending on the RAID controller.

Answer (score 0):

> My question is, what problems can I face when moving the disks to the new hardware, can I encounter any driver issues or something similar or it should work without a problem as long as the cpu architecture is the same (intel xeon x64) ?

If your server is a public facing server with **static IP addresses and more than one NIC** then one thing you may have to change is the Interface to Mac address mapping in the `70-persistent-net.rules`. This file is easy to change and anytime I restore a clone its a 50/50 chance that the interfaces get messed up.

Just edit this file from after you bring the new hardware up: `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules`

I usually comment out all the (old) previous rules and then check if the interfaces that got auto mapped are set up like I want them on the new hardware, id. eth0, eth1.

But overall you should be able to get the hardware back up very quickly.